# rtl for cards with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have  this list of cards working with angularJs based on this tutorial: [Demo][1]

```
<div id='cont'>
 <flippy class="fancy "  id="divID" ng-repeat="card in cards" flip="['click']" flip-back="['click']" duration="800" timing-function="ease-in-out" >
    <flippy-back>
        <h3 ng-model="card.text">{{card.text}} <h3/>
    </flippy-back>
    <flippy-front>
        <h5>{{card.num}}<h5/>
    </flippy-front>
 </flippy>
```

Using bootstrap rtl I applied the rtl for all my interfaces unless for  cards. this is any way to display my cards like this : 3 2 1

Answer (score 1):

If you stored 1 2 3 in an array in javascript you can simply use reverse()

```
var array = [1,2,3];
array.reverse();
```